# iterating an object properties

Tags: javascript

is there a way to iterate an object properties and methods. i need to write a utility function like so:

```
function iterate(obj)
{
    //print all obj properties     
    //print all obj methods
}
```

so running this function:

```
iterate(String);
```

will print:

```
property: lenght
function: charAt
function: concat...
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See my answer in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200562/difference-in-json-objects-using-javascript-jquery/1200713#1200713), but you can't read built-in properties like that.

Answer (score 13):

Should be as simple as this:

```
function iterate(obj) {
    for (p in obj) {
        console.log(typeof(obj[p]), p);
    }
}
```

Note: The `console.log` function is assuming you are using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). At this point, the following:

```
obj = {
    p1: 1, 
    p2: "two",
    m1: function() {}
};

iterate(obj);
```

would return:

```
number p1
string p2
function m1
```

Comment: it seems that running your example works.
However when i used the String class it didn't return anything. 

iterate(String);

I also tried: 
var s = "sss";
iterate(s);

Comment: When you iterate a string, it will step through each character. Try passing String(s) instead, to wrap the string in an object.

Answer (score 3):

**This only works in modern browsers** (Chrome, Firefox 4+, IE9+), but in ECMAScript 5, you can get all the properties of an object with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`. It just takes a little extra code to get the inherited properties from the prototype.

```
// Put all the properties of an object (including inherited properties) into
// an object so they can be iterated over
function getProperties(obj, properties) {
    properties = properties || {};

    // Get the prototype's properties
    var prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    if (prototype !== null) {
        getProperties(prototype, properties);
    }

    // Get obj's own properties
    var names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        var name = names[i];
        properties[name] = obj[name];
    }

    return properties;
}

function iterate(obj) {
    obj = Object(obj);

    var properties = getProperties(obj);

    for (var name in properties) {
        if (typeof properties[name] !== "function") {
            console.log("property: " + name);
        }
    }
    for (var name in properties) {
        if (typeof properties[name] === "function") {
            console.log("function: " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the for loop to iterate an object's properties.

Here is a simple example

```
var o ={'test':'test', 'blah':'blah'};

for(var p in o)
    alert(p);
```

Comment: What if the property is a key for an object?