# jQuery - look through object key => val?

Tags: jquery, json

I am passing back a JSON object to jQuery. I need it to look through the JSON object and effectively do this.

```
$(key).css('background-color', '#'+val);
```

In php I would use a foreach loop. Does javascript have something similar? How would I go about doing this?

JSON

```
{
  '.one' : 'AAA',
  '.two' : 'BBB'
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iterating an object properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214873/iterating-an-object-properties)

Comment: Also see: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [each function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) of jQuery:

```
var map = { 
  '.one': 'AAA', 
  '.two': 'BBB' 
};
$.each(map, function(key, val) { 
  $(key).css('background-color', '#'+val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method

```
jQuery.each(JSONobject, function(key, value) {
    $(key).css('background-color', '#'+value);
});
```

You can also use `this` instead of `value` in the function, because the function is executed in the context of each element.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQUery has an each function

$.each(yourJsonObject, function(key, value) {
    //whatever processing
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var data = {
  '.one' : 'AAA',
  '.two' : 'BBB'
};

for (var key in data)
    if (typeof(data[key]) == 'string')
        $(key).css('background-color', '#' + data[key]);
```

A JSFiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/r7s96/

Comment: you should use `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: I wanted to filter out all non-string members. Adding another condition with hasOwnProperty would have no meaning here.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery

```
var data = {
    '.one' : 'AAA',
    '.two' : 'BBB'
};

$.each(data, function(key, value){
    $(key).css('background-color', '#' + value);
})
```