# Angular watch with true - which property was changed

Tags: angularjs

I have an object with deep watch on  it (true in the third argument of $watch).
When the watch is triggered I want to know which property was changed. All I'm getting is the new and old value. Is there a good way to know what was changed? I don't want to compare new and old objects and search for the changed properties.

Comment: That is just how it works. You could watch the properties individually if you really do not want to write code to figure it out.

Comment: Or try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572826/generic-deep-diff-between-two-objects

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest way, but a non pure AngularJS way to solve this is to use `Object.observe()` on the object instead of $watch, because it passes on the name of the changed property.

#### External links for Object.observe()

- [Article - Respond to change with Object.observe](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/11/Respond-to-change-with-Object-observe)
- [Compatability table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/#Object.observe_%28part_of_b_ES7_/b_%29)
- [Polyfill](https://github.com/jdarling/Object.observe)

---

Another way would be to override the getters and setters on the object so they create a changed property list that is stored internally in the object. Not sure about the exact implementation of this, and it isn't that clean either.