# Compare two deep nested object of objects and return only the differences in javascript / lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash, javascript-objects

I have 2 deep nested object of objects. One is a "base" object and the other is a modified one.

I essentially want to "delete" the base object from the modified object and return an object that only contains different data. Here is an example:

Base object:

```
baseObj : {
    image: {
        width: '100%',
        paddingTop: '0px',
        paddingRight: '0px',
        paddingBottom: '0px',
        paddingLeft: '0px'
    },
    wrap: {
        marginTop: '0px',
        marginRight: '0px',
        marginBottom: '0px',
        marginLeft: '0px'
    }
}
```

Object with modified data

```
mergedObject : {
    image: {
        width: '100%',  
        paddingTop: '0px',
        paddingRight: '24px', // modified value
        paddingBottom: '24px', // modified value
        paddingLeft: '0px'
    },
    wrap: {
        height: '100px', // new value
        marginTop: '24px', // modified value
        marginRight: '0px',
        marginBottom: '0px',
        marginLeft: '24px' // modified value
    }
}
```

I would like an object that is returned like this:

```
diffObject : {
    image: {
        paddingRight: '24px',
        paddingBottom: '24px',
    },
    wrap: {
        height: '100px',
        marginTop: '24px',
        marginLeft: '24px'
    }
}
```

The nesting could go a little deeper so it needs to be dynamic. Is there a way using lodash or some other library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic deep diff between two objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572826/generic-deep-diff-between-two-objects)

Comment: Thanks. I found a jsfiddle on that page: http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/9g5qoxwj/ It almost does what i need. However it returns empty objects such as this: "diff(a, b) = "  {"x":4,"z":{},"zz":{"a":1,"b":2}}  
"diff(a, b) = "  {"x":56,"z":{},"zz":{"a":2,"b":1}}. If I can find a way to remove the z:{} value then it's perfect

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, we must:

- Create a function that traverses each node in the object recursively. We can achieve this by using the [reduce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#reduce) function when traversing the `source` object.
- The `reduce` callback function would first check if the `source` value or it's `other` value counter part are both objects. If they are, we'll use these values as arguments to recursively get the difference of both these objects. Otherwise, if they are different, then we'll assign the resulting value from the `other` value.
- Lastly, the `reduce` function accepts a third argument which is used as the initial value for the accumulated of the `reduce` function. We assign the third argument with key-values from the `other` object that aren't found in the `source` object. This is the simplest way to get the newly introduced values from the `other` object towards the resulting object.

---

```
function differenceObjectDeep(source, other) {
  return _.reduce(source, function(result, value, key) {
    if (_.isObject(value) && _.isObject(other[key])) {
      result[key] = differenceObjectDeep(
        value,
        other[key]
      );
    } else if (!_.isEqual(value, other[key])) {
      result[key] = other[key];
    }
    return result;
  }, _.omit(other, _.keys(source)));
}

data.diffObject = differenceObjectDeep(
  data.baseObj,
  data.mergedObject
);
```

```js
var data = {
  baseObj: {
    image: {
      width: '100%',
      paddingTop: '0px',
      paddingRight: '0px',
      paddingBottom: '0px',
      paddingLeft: '0px'
    },
    wrap: {
      marginTop: '0px',
      marginRight: '0px',
      marginBottom: '0px',
      marginLeft: '0px'
    }
  },
  mergedObject: {
    image: {
      width: '100%',
      paddingTop: '0px',
      paddingRight: '24px', // modified value
      paddingBottom: '24px', // modified value
      paddingLeft: '0px'
    },
    wrap: {
      height: '100px', // new value
      marginTop: '24px', // modified value
      marginRight: '0px',
      marginBottom: '0px',
      marginLeft: '24px' // modified value
    }
  }
};

function differenceObjectDeep(source, other) {
  return _.reduce(source, function(result, value, key) {
    if (_.isObject(value) && _.isObject(other[key])) {
      result[key] = differenceObjectDeep(
        value,
        other[key]
      );
    } else if (!_.isEqual(value, other[key])) {
      result[key] = other[key];
    }
    return result;
  }, _.omit(other, _.keys(source)));
}

data.diffObject = differenceObjectDeep(
  data.baseObj,
  data.mergedObject
);

console.log(data.diffObject);
```

```css
body>div {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use recursive function to find the last object.

```
var checkIfObject = function(item){ //recursive function
_.each(item, function(v, k){
if(_.isObject(v)){
previousObject = k;
previousResult = v;
return checkIfObject(v);
}else{
    finalChildObjects[previousObject] = previousResult;
}
})
return finalChildObjects
}

/*Initialize Values for recursive function*/
var finalChildObjects = {};
var previousObject = '';
var previousResult = '';
baseObjectFinalTurn = checkIfObject(baseObj);
/*Initialize Values for recursive function*/
var finalChildObjects = {};
var previousObject = '';
var previousResult = '';
mergedObjectFinalTurn = checkIfObject(mergedObject);
console.clear();


var difference = {};
_.each(baseObjectFinalTurn, function(v, k){
    if(mergedObjectFinalTurn[k]){
    difference[k] = _.reduce(mergedObjectFinalTurn[k],function(result, value, key){
    if(baseObjectFinalTurn[k][key] != mergedObjectFinalTurn[k][key]){
    result[key] =  value;
    }
    
    return result
    }, {})
    
  }
  else{
  difference[k] = {};
  }
})

console.log(difference)
```

You can verify the result from this [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/yx4ck723/)

Note: you need to adjust the result based on your requirement in reduce. This result is made to match your output.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I ran the fiddle and all i see in the console is an object returning true or false. I need it to be the actual different data

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update the fiddle. Thanks to fiddle for having the local draft. Here is the updated code https://jsfiddle.net/yx4ck723/4/