# How to get the Angular changing key from $scope.$watch(..., true)

Tags: angularjs, watch

I am deep watching an object in Angular,

```
$scope.$watch('bigObject', function(newVal, oldVal, scope) { //Watch the whole object
    console.log("The key that changed was: " + key);
}, true); //Deep watch
```

**How do I get the key that changed?**

Example output: `The key that changed was: bigObject.users.john.birthday`

Comment: I'd think of using [Generic deep diff between two objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25651677/2435473)

Answer (score 0):

Try for this:

```
 $scope.$watch('bigObject', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
    //Do anything with $scope.letters
    if(oldValue.users.john.birthday == newValue.users.john.birthday){
      //nothing chages
    }
    else{
       // write your logic here after changinging value    
      }
            console.log(newValue.users.john.birthday);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not trying to get the value itself. I'm trying to get the key that changed.

Comment: but it should be insure that your users, object must have john object and john object must have birthday property

Comment: What do you mean? The key wouldn't change, the key (birthday in the example) would be the same.

Comment: Now i have ediited in my answer so plz try for that

Comment: Thanks, but still not what I'm looking for. Imagine it like a logger, I want to log all keys that change. I can't know which key is going to change. In fact I have no information about the object itself.

Comment: No problem, $watch is always subscribing to that object, whenever you wiil change in bigObject,

But i think we need to check, what parameter of the object is changing, thats why we wrote condition in our case. otherwise how we can detect,

in case of chaging, it will automatically called. and implement your business logic.