# How to compare two redux store states?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, jestjs, immutable.js

I am writing tests for my reducers and would like to compare state before dispatch to state after - actually 'substract' before state from after state

```
describe('UpdateAccountData', () => {
    let store;

    describe('Customer', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            store = createStore(reducers, customerData, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));
        });

        it('debug store', () => {
            console.log(store.getState());
        });

        it('dispatch change', () => {
            //need to deep copy old state here
            store.dispatch(updateStoredCustomerDetails({ email: 'blabla@blabla.com' }));
            console.log(store.getState());
            //need to substract old state from new state to check that only email has changed and nothing else
        });
    });
```

Comment: refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572826/generic-deep-diff-between-two-objects you just need to check the difference bewteen the two objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the deep object diff library, here is my example - I am testing that there are no other changes except email in two occurrences:

```
import { updatedDiff, deletedDiff, addedDiff } from 'deep-object-diff';  
               .....

        it('updates customer email', () => {
            const before = store.getState();
            store.dispatch(updateStoredCustomerDetails({ email: 'blabla@blabla.com' }));
            const after = store.getState();
            expect(addedDiff(before, after)).toEqual({});
            expect(deletedDiff(before, after)).toEqual({});
            expect(updatedDiff(before, after)).toEqual({
                login: { loginToken: { email: 'blabla@blabla.com' } },
                customer: { email: 'blabla@blabla.com' },
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [equals](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/equals) method like this:

```
oldStore.equals(newStore); //Returns boolean
```