# getting difference object from two objects using es6

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

Im trying to figure out whats the best way to get an intersection object between two objects using es6.
by this i mean something like:

```
a = {a:'a',b:'b',c:'c', d:'d'};
b = {a:'a',b: '1', c:'c', d:'2', f'!!!'}
// result I want:
c = getDifference(a,b)
//c is now: {b:'1', d:'2'}
```

Is there a short way to do this using es6, or do I need to iterate over the a object using for(in) with Object.keys() and compare, assigning intersections to c?

```
(a,b) => {
    const c = {};
    for(const _key in Object.keys(a)){
       if(b[_key] && b[_key] !== a[_key]){
           c[_key] = b[_key];
       }
    }
    return c;
}
```

I know loadash/underscore has these kinds of helper functions... but trying to see if es6 has any new short syntax for this, and if not whats the shortest way to do this using vanilla js.

Comment: Common misconception debunked - ES6 **is** vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: yes... I know... I say Es6 to emphasize that im talking about es6 and above since both es6 & es7 has a lot of new features maybe im missing a short way to do this...

Comment: Shouldn't `c` have also `f` key? It's unclear what you mean by "difference". Do you need to get differences of a against b and vice-versa or just one against the other? Also, how would you handle nested objects?..

Comment: ammm... no I should of probably used the word -intersection- instead of -difference- I'll edit this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the entries of object `b` using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then filter out the key-value pairs which are the same as those in `a` using `.filter()`, then, you can rebuild your object using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) like so:

```js
const a = {a:'a',b:'b',c:'c', d:'d'};
const b = {a:'a',b: '1', c:'c', d:'2', f:'!!!'}

const getDifference = (a, b) => 
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(b).filter(([key, val]) => key in a && a[key] !== val));


// result I want:
const c = getDifference(a,b); // peforms b-a
console.log(c); // {b:'1', d:'2'}
```

If you can't support `Object.fromEntries()`, then you can use `.reduce()` instead to build the object for you:

```js
const a = {a:'a',b:'b',c:'c', d:'d'};
const b = {a:'a',b: '1', c:'c', d:'2', f:'!!!'}

const getDifference = (a, b) => 
  Object.entries(b).filter(([key, val]) => a[key] !== val && key in a).reduce((a, [key, v]) => ({...a, [key]: v}), {});


// result I want:
const c = getDifference(a,b); // peforms b-a
console.log(c); // {b:'1', d:'2'}
```

Comment: second solution works out of the box... and you provided future solution... nice

Comment: Doesn't work with nested objects.

Comment: @Ariakas You can modify the answer above to use recursion to make it work with deeply nested objects (that was out of scope for this question, so not included in my answer). See this question for details: [Generic deep diff between two objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8572826)

Answer (score 6):

Use `reduce` for more concise code, but your approach was the clearest:

```
const getDifference = (a, b) => Object.entries(a).reduce((ac, [k, v]) => b[k] && b[k] !== v ? (ac[k] = b[k], ac) : ac, {});
```

We use `Object.entries` to avoid getting the value if we used `Object.keys` - it's just easier. Since `b[k]` may not exist, we use the short-circuit logical AND `&&` operator - so if a key from `a` *doesn't* exist in `b`, it's not added to the result object. Then we check if the two values are equal - if they *are*, then nothing needs to be added, but if they're *not*, we add the key and value from `b` to the result object. In both cases, we return the result object.

Comment: Upvoting since you're the only one that actually mentioned that your solution has no benefits other than being more concise than the original one (neither more efficient, nor actually much conceptually different).

Comment: Thanks @briosheje, always good to know I'm getting stuff right!

Comment: Can you explain your code a bit? I can't get it :/ Looks like a nice approach

Comment: Done @weegee, how's that?

Comment: Just Perfect. Thanks a lot

Comment: No worries @weegee, always glad to help.

Comment: @JackBashford Did you try that code? It returns `{a: "a", b: "b", c: "c", d: "d"}`, Which not match with OP's expected outcome

Comment: My bad @NeelRathod, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a single short with `Object.keys()`;

```js
const mainObj = {
  a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c', d: 'd',
};
const comapareObj = {
  a: 'a', b: '1', c: 'c', d: '2', f: '!!!',
};

const findVariantsElement = (main, compareWith) => {
  const result = {};
  Object.keys(main).forEach((r) => {
    const element = main[r];
    if (compareWith[r]) {
      if (element !== compareWith[r]) {
        result[r] = compareWith[r];
      }
    }
  });
  return result;
};

const c = findVariantsElement(mainObj, comapareObj);
console.log(c);
```

You can use `.map()` also for the same

```js
const mainObj = {
  a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c', d: 'd',
};
const comapareObj = {
  a: 'a', b: '1', c: 'c', d: '2', f: '!!!',
};

const findVariantsElement = (main, compareWith) => {
  const result = {};
  Object.keys(main).map((r) => {
    const element = main[r];
    if (compareWith[r]) {
      if (element !== compareWith[r]) {
        result[r] = compareWith[r];
      }
    }
  });
  return result;
};

const c = findVariantsElement(mainObj, comapareObj);
console.log(c);
```