# JavaScript - Return differences between two Objects?

Tags: javascript, object

Can someone show me how to return the new data when comparing something like this. using vanilla JavaScript.

```
{
    "48": "{\"sid\":\"48\",\"name\":\"title 1\"}",
    "77": "{\"sid\":\"77\",\"name\":\"The blahblah title\"}"
}
```

compared to this

```
{
    "48": "{\"sid\":\"48\",\"name\":\"title 1\"}",
    "77": "{\"sid\":\"77\",\"name\":\"The blahblah title\"}",
    "83": "{\"sid\":\"83\",\"name\":\"The blahblah derp\"}",
    "87": "{\"sid\":\"87\",\"name\":\"The derpy title 4\"}"
}
```

it should return only the differences.

```
{
    "83": "{\"sid\":\"83\",\"name\":\"The blahblah derp\"}",
    "87": "{\"sid\":\"87\",\"name\":\"The derpy title 4\"}"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: They are not multidimensional, they are flat objects. `[key: string]: string;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting difference object from two objects using es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57669696/getting-difference-object-from-two-objects-using-es6)

Comment: I give really nice answered  here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71173966/1919821

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to do that.

```js
var data = {
  "48": "{\"sid\":\"48\",\"name\":\"title 1\"}",
  "77": "{\"sid\":\"77\",\"name\":\"The blahblah title\"}",
  "83": "{\"sid\":\"83\",\"name\":\"The blahblah derp\"}",
  "87": "{\"sid\":\"87\",\"name\":\"The derpy title 4\"}"
};

var obj1 = {
  "48": "{\"sid\":\"48\",\"name\":\"title 1\"}",
  "77": "{\"sid\":\"77\",\"name\":\"The blahblah title\"}"
};

var result = {};
var keys = Object.keys(obj1);

for (var key in data) {
 if (!keys.includes(key)) {
  result[key] = data[key];
 }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This approach will only work if data has more keys and is the primary object to compare to.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Acidic - That is what is asked by OP. And the object comparing with (`data` here) will always be the superset.

Comment: Any idea what the benchmarks or performance hit for using lodash.includes instead of prototype.includes?

Answer (score 6):

An object oriented approach using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const obj1 = {
  '48': '{"sid":"48","name":"title 1"}',
  '77': '{"sid":"77","name":"The blahblah title"}',
}

const obj2 = {
  '48': '{"sid":"48","name":"title 1"}',
  '77': '{"sid":"77","name":"The blahblah title"}',
  '83': '{"sid":"83","name":"The blahblah derp"}',
  '87': '{"sid":"87","name":"The derpy title 4"}',
}

const combinedObject = { ...obj1, ...obj2 }

const diff = Object.entries(combinedObject).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  if (
    !Object.values(obj1).includes(value) ||
    !Object.values(obj2).includes(value)
  )
    acc[key] = value

  return acc
}, {})

console.log(diff)
```

This approach will work with several objects and does not treat one object as the primary one for comparison.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Object.prototype.entries` and `Array.prototype.reduce`.

```js
const a = {
    "48": "{\"sid\":\"48\",\"name\":\"title 1\"}",
    "77": "{\"sid\":\"77\",\"name\":\"The blahblah title\"}"
};
const b = {
    "48": "{\"sid\":\"48\",\"name\":\"title 1\"}",
    "77": "{\"sid\":\"77\",\"name\":\"The blahblah title\"}",
    "83": "{\"sid\":\"83\",\"name\":\"The blahblah derp\"}",
    "87": "{\"sid\":\"87\",\"name\":\"The derpy title 4\"}"
};

const c = Object.entries(b).reduce((c, [k, v]) => Object.assign(c, a[k] ? {} : { [k]: v }), {});

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply iterate the second object & check if this key exist in first object. If not then in a new object add this key and its value.

```js
let data1 = {
  "48": "{\"sid\":\"48\",\"name\":\"title 1\"}",
  "77": "{\"sid\":\"77\",\"name\":\"The blahblah title\"}"
}
let data2 = {
  "48": "{\"sid\":\"48\",\"name\":\"title 1\"}",
  "77": "{\"sid\":\"77\",\"name\":\"The blahblah title\"}",
  "83": "{\"sid\":\"83\",\"name\":\"The blahblah derp\"}",
  "87": "{\"sid\":\"87\",\"name\":\"The derpy title 4\"}"
}

let newObj = {};

for (let keys in data2) {
  if (!data1[keys]) {
    newObj[keys] = data2[keys]
  }
};

console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a procedure in which the order of the objects to compare does not matter

Code:

```js
const obj1 = {
  "48": "{\"sid\":\"48\",\"name\":\"title 1\"}",
  "77": "{\"sid\":\"77\",\"name\":\"The blahblah title\"}"
}
const obj2 = {
  "48": "{\"sid\":\"48\",\"name\":\"title 1\"}",
  "77": "{\"sid\":\"77\",\"name\":\"The blahblah title\"}",
  "83": "{\"sid\":\"83\",\"name\":\"The blahblah derp\"}",
  "87": "{\"sid\":\"87\",\"name\":\"The derpy title 4\"}"
}

const getDiffObj = (o1, o2) =>  Object.keys(o1)
    .filter(k => !Object.keys(o2).includes(k))
    .concat(Object.keys(o2).filter(k => !Object.keys(o1).includes(k)))
    .map(k => o1[k] || o2[k])

console.log(getDiffObj(obj1, obj2))
console.log(getDiffObj(obj2, obj1))
```