# How to get the difference between two objects?

Tags: javascript, lodash

If I have two objects:

```
const objA = { name: 'Tom', age: '20', location: 'London' };
const objB = { name: 'Jimmy', age: '35', occupation: 'Welder', hobbies: ['Football'] }
```

How can I get only the values that are only present in objA and not in objB, I want the result to be:

```
{
    location: 'London'
}
```

Is there a method in Lodash for that?

Comment: Combining `Object.keys` and https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#difference looks like it might work?

Comment: Maybe this help you.
Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57669696/getting-difference-object-from-two-objects-using-es6)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks. Is there something for objects and not arrays? `difference` will return the different keys indeed, but I'll need to construct the new object myself and I want to avoid this

Comment: `How can I get only the values that are only present in objA and not in objB` you mean **keys**?

Comment: @GrafiCode: The output looks more like the key-value pair(s).

Comment: @GrafiCode no, I mean key-value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`_.pickBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pickBy) and [`_.has()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#has) to get the desired result using lodash.

We'll use the predicate: (value, key) => !_.has(objB, key) to return entries only present in objA.

```js
const objA = { name: 'Tom', age: '20', location: 'London' };
const objB = { name: 'Jimmy', age: '35', occupation: 'Welder', hobbies: ['Football'] }

const difference = _.pickBy(objA, (value, key) => !_.has(objB, key));
console.log('Difference:', difference)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

You can also do this in vanilla JavaScript using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const objA = { name: 'Tom', age: '20', location: 'London' };
const objB = { name: 'Jimmy', age: '35', occupation: 'Welder', hobbies: ['Football'] }

const difference = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(objA).filter(([key, value]) => {
        return !objB.hasOwnProperty(key);
    })
);

console.log('Difference:', difference)
```

Answer (score 4):

Native, modern JS only:

```js
const objA = { name: 'Tom', age: '20', location: 'London' };
const objB = { name: 'Jimmy', age: '35', occupation: 'Welder', hobbies: ['Football'] };

const diff = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(objA).filter(([k, v]) => !Object.hasOwn(objB, k)));

console.log(diff);
```

Please note that this solution makes use of several relatively new additions to JavaScript:

- [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (ES 2017)
- [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) (ES 2019)
- [`Object.hasOwn()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) (ES 2022)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried something like this?

```
for (key in objA) {
  if (!objB[key]) {
    console.log(key, objA[key]);
  }
}
```

or something like:

```
let newObj = {};

for (key in objA) {
  if (!objB[key]) {
    newObj[key] = objA[key];
  }
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: Better to use `Object.hasOwnProperty`. That way you can also find falsy object values and exclude attributes defined in the prototype.