# Simple git-like diff of two JSONs in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, diff

So let's show it by example. I have to JSONs:

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": 1,
        "c": 2
    },
    "d": false,
    "e": 15,
    "f": "something important"
}
```

and

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": 1,
        "c": 22
    },
    "d": false,
    "e": "fifteen",
    "g": "something new"
}
```

and the result I want is:

```
b: 2 => 22
e: 15 => "fifteen"
f(deleted)
g(created) "something new"
```

So basically I need a simple diff to show what changed in the model that I got from backend, but I'm not sure if I should look for a library or is it easy enough that it's possible to do with one function.

Comment: first step ... parse the JSON into javascript objects - the next part should write itself once you are not dealing with strings

Comment: There is nothing simple about git diff :)

Comment: Take a look at `for (x in y)` loop and `object.hasOwnProperty()` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic deep diff between two objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572826/generic-deep-diff-between-two-objects)

Comment: try something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-diff

Answer (score 1):

You could check the parts and get a result by checking the nested parts as well.

```js
function getDifference(a, b) {
    return [...new Set([...Object.keys(a), ...Object.keys(b)])].reduce((r, k) => {

        if (a[k] && b[k] && typeof a[k] === 'object' && typeof b[k] === 'object') {
            var temp = getDifference(a[k], b[k]);
            if (temp.length) r.push(...temp.map(([l, ...a]) => [k + ' ' + l, ...a]));
            return r;
        }

        if (k in a && !(k in b)) {
            r.push([k, 'deleted', a[k]]);
            return r;
        }

        if (!(k in a) && k in b) {
            r.push([k, 'created', b[k]]);
            return r;
        }

        if (a[k] === b[k]) return r;

        r.push([k, 'changed', a[k], b[k]]);
        return r;
    }, []);
}



console.log(getDifference(
    { a: { b: 1, c: 2 }, d: false, e: 15, f: "something important" },
    { a: { b: 1, c: 22 }, d: false, e: "fifteen", g: "something new" }
));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-diff

Really easy to use and provide a detailed diff with filter method and tooling around diff like approving change or not for example.

Answer (score -1):

Affiliation: I am the author of this lib.

What about this?

https://eggachecat.github.io/jycm-json-diff-viewer/

You can easily complete your task. But more interestingly, if "e" is something like "timestamp" which almost gauratees change, You can ignore this by simply do a config.

[image]

Step by step:

1. install deps

```bash
yarn add jycm
```

2. use the lib

```js
const {
    YouchamaJsonDiffer,
    ListItemFieldMatchOperator,
    make_ignore_order_func
} = require('jycm');

const left = {
    "a": {
        "b": 1,
        "c": 2
    },
    "d": false,
    "e": 15,
    "f": "something important"
};

const right = {
    "a": {
        "b": 1,
        "c": 22
    },
    "d": false,
    "e": "fifteen",
    "g": "something new"
};

const ycm = new YouchamaJsonDiffer(left, right, {
  "operators": [
  
  ],
  "ignore_orders": [
  ]
});
const diffResult = ycm.get_diff(true);
console.log(diffResult);
```

You can get

```json
{
  "dict:add": [
    {
      "left": "__NON_EXIST__",
      "right": "something new",
      "left_path": "",
      "right_path": "g"
    }
  ],
  "dict:remove": [
    {
      "left": "something important",
      "right": "__NON_EXIST__",
      "left_path": "f",
      "right_path": ""
    }
  ],
  "value_changes": [
    {
      "left": 2,
      "right": 22,
      "left_path": "a->c",
      "right_path": "a->c",
      "old": 2,
      "new": 22
    },
    {
      "left": 15,
      "right": "fifteen",
      "left_path": "e",
      "right_path": "e",
      "old": 15,
      "new": "fifteen"
    }
  ]
}
```

3. make use of the result

```js
diffResult["value_changes"].map(record => console.log(`${record.left_path}: ${record.old} => ${record.new} `))
diffResult["dict:remove"].map(record => console.log(`${record.left_path}(deleted)`))
diffResult["dict:add"].map(record => console.log(`${record.right_path}(created) ${record.new}`))
```

Or here's a codesniffet:

```js
const {
  YouchamaJsonDiffer,
  ListItemFieldMatchOperator,
  make_ignore_order_func,
} = jycm;

const left = {
    "a": {
        "b": 1,
        "c": 2
    },
    "d": false,
    "e": 15,
    "f": "something important"
};

const right = {
    "a": {
        "b": 1,
        "c": 22
    },
    "d": false,
    "e": "fifteen",
    "g": "something new"
};

const ycm = new YouchamaJsonDiffer(left, right, {
  "operators": [
  
  ],
  "ignore_orders": [
  ]
});

const diffResult = ycm.get_diff(true);
diffResult["value_changes"].map(record => console.log(`${record.left_path}: ${record.old} => ${record.new} `))

diffResult["dict:remove"].map(record => console.log(`${record.left_path}(deleted)`))
diffResult["dict:add"].map(record => console.log(`${record.right_path}(created) ${record.new}`))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jycm@0.2.0/dist/index.js"></script>
```