# Firebase onSnapshot() listener... Can I somehow get data from before change

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in a firebase. I'm listening to changes with `onSnapshot` method.

If any item from a collection is changed in any way listener is fired. I am getting new data, which was inserted into my collection with `docChanges` method

```
db.collection('collection')
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
            const payload = {
                id: change.doc.id,
                data: change.doc.data(),
            };

            ...... some action
        });
    });
```

and now... I need to compare new data (which was just inserted) with old data (from before insert) and I am wondering if there is any way to do that?

Comment: Could you edit the question to be more clear, showing a specific example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: okaay I've upadted question

Comment: I think onSnapshot happens too late.  A cloud function onUpdate provides a change object that has before and after properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firestore SDK doesn't give you any ways to detect the differences between the "before" and "after" states of a document's fields.  You will have to remember both snapshots and look for differences in the fields yourself.  You might want to do a search for some ideas on how to go about this, for example: [Generic deep diff between two objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572826/generic-deep-diff-between-two-objects)