# react - function to return the changes of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's assume I have below object

```
let obj = {
    id:1,
    likes: 20,
    createdBy: 'tom'
}
```

Then I create new object which is used to record the changes.

```
let dynamicObject = obj;
obj.likes = 30;
createdBy = 'ken';

// which should be
//  {
//     id:1,
//     likes: 30,
//     createdBy: 'ken'
//  }
```

I want to create a function like below, so as to get the changes of the object for my PATCH request.

```
someFunc(obj, dynamicObject)
```

which return

```
 {
    likes: 30,
    createdBy: 'ken'
 }
```

Is there any library or method to do it?

Comment: You are probably looking into object diff https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572826/generic-deep-diff-between-two-objects. Btw you are not creating a new object with `dynamicObject = obj`. It's still pass by reference

Comment: @Murat Karagöz yes..it's just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a deep equality function with a small modification, like this:

```
const diffObjects = (x, y, z) => {
  if (x === y) return {};
  if (!(x instanceof Object) || !(y instanceof Object)) return 'ALL';
  if (x.constructor !== y.constructor) return 'ALL';
  for (var p in x) {
    if (!x.hasOwnProperty(p)) continue;
    if (!y.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      z[p] = x[p];
      continue;
    }
    if (x[p] === y[p]) continue;
    if (typeof (x[p]) !== 'object') {
      z[p] = y[p];
      continue;
    }
    const z1 = {};
    diffObjects(x[p], y[p], z1);
    if (JSON.stringify(z1) !== '{}') { z[p] = z1; }
  }
  for (p in y) { if (y.hasOwnProperty(p) && !x.hasOwnProperty(p)) z[p] = y[p]; }
  return z;
};

console.log(diffObjects(obj1, obj2, {}));
```

Comment: Much like the answer @Murat posted in the comments?

Comment: yes, sorry it's similar...I was writing this example. This code should return data as you ask

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use an external library like [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/).

It will make object manipulation easier (especially if used with React) *and* provides [patches feature](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/patches), from which you can access every diff in a user friendly way.