# How can i compare 2 Json document and find the difference between them in Marklogic using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, marklogic

How can i compare two Json document's  and  find the difference between them in Marklogic using javascript?

Comment: In XPath 3.1 you can use the deep-equal() function, but I don't know for sure whether that works in MarkLogic. Also it doesn't "find the difference", it just tells you whether they are equal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8572826/14419

Answer (score -1):

To compare 2 JSON Objects, you could just use **The following function**:

```js
const areTheSame = (foo, bar) => JSON.stringify(foo) == JSON.stringify(bar);

// Example:
areTheSame({foo: 'bar'}, {foo: 'bar'}) // true
```

**EDIT:** As i mentionned, you cannot find the difference of 2 Objects...
Good Luck!

Comment: That's not going to work, because the order of entries in a map/object when stringified is undefined.