# React: How to show delete confirmation alert on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying data with radio buttons. Once user select a radio button and then submit click, delete confirmation dialog will appear, click yes will delete the item and no will cancel the dialog. How to achieve this?
Also, how to get the selected radiobutton item id in submit handler?

```
import React from "react";
export class DeleteFeature extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.state = {
                     FeatureID: "",
                     FeatureTextPlain: "",
                     Feature: [], loading: true,
              };
              this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
              this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
       }
       componentDidMount() {
                     this.DisplayFeatures();
       }
       componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
              if (prevProps.key_id !== this.props.key_id) {
                     console.log(`key_id: ${this.props.key_id}`);
                     this.DisplayFeatures();
              }
       }
       DisplayFeatures() {
              fetch(REQUEST_URL)
                     .then(response => response.json())
                     .then((data) => {
                           this.setState({
                                  Feature: data,
                                  loading: false
                           })
                     })
                     .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
       }
       handleChange(event) {
              this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
       }
       handleSubmit(event) {
              event.preventDefault(); 
              fetch(REQUEST_URL, {
                     method: 'POST',
                     body: JSON.stringify(data),
                     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
              })
                     .then(response => response.json())
                     .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
       }
       render() {
              return (
                     <div>
                           <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
<tbody>
       {this.state.Feature.map((item, index) => {
              return [
                     <div width="100%">
                           <tr><td width="5%">
                                  <input type="radio" id={item.FeatureID} onChange={this.handleChange} /> </td>
                                  <td width="68%" valign="top" align="left" >{item.featureTextPlain}</td></tr>
                     </div>];
       })}</tbody></table> 
<button type="submit" name="submit" >Delete</button>
</form></div>
              );
       }
}
export default DeleteFeature;
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a radio element so that only one item is deleted, or is it expected from the UI to delete multiple items on dialog confirm?

Comment: Only one item needs to be deleted. So only one radio button can be selected.

Comment: ON Dialog confirm yes will delete only one item. Please tell how to show confirm dialog?

Comment: Showing a dialog should probably be handled by a library not by yourself, reactstrap's modal might help, other Modals components are found in the community

Comment: With the broad selection of libraries providing modals/dialogs components I can't post an answer to the question, but if you're already using bootstrap then reactstrap is your obvious choice, what CSS framework are you using if any?