# React difference object

Tags: reactjs, difference

How to find the difference between two objects.

I have two const

> const initialData = {
> Phases: [
> {
> PhaseName: '44',
> Comment: '44',
> Servers: [
> {
> ServerName: '44',
> Comment: '44',
> IP: '44',
> User: '44',
> PwdEncrypted:
> '44444',
> },
> ],
> },
> {
> PhaseName: '55',
> Comment: '55',
> Servers: [
> {
> ServerName: '55',
> Comment: '55',
> IP: '55',
> User: '55',
> PwdEncrypted: '55',
> },
> ],
> },
> ],
> };

> const initialData2 = {
> Phases: [
> {
> PhaseName: '66666',
> Comment: '44',
> Servers: [
> {
> ServerName: '44',
> Comment: '44',
> IP: '44',
> User: '44',
> PwdEncrypted:
> '44444',
> },
> ],
> },
> {
> PhaseName: '55',
> Comment: '55',
> Servers: [
> {
> ServerName: '55',
> Comment: '55',
> IP: '55',
> User: '55',
> PwdEncrypted: '55',
> },
> ],
> },
> ],
> };

I only want to see the difference "66666"

Comment: Check this old question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572826/generic-deep-diff-between-two-objects

Comment: Very thanks i use https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-object-diff

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic deep diff between two objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572826/generic-deep-diff-between-two-objects)