# Find the difference between two complex objects containing array of objects

Tags: javascript, object, difference, arrayofarrays

```
let baseObj =  {
    place: {city: 'Bangalore', pin: 123456},
    office: [
        { name: 'Tom', age: 22, salutation: { title: 'Mr'}}, 
        { name: 'John', age: 31, salutation: { title: 'Mr'}}
    ]
} 
let updatedObj = {
place: {city: 'Bangalore', pin: 99999},
    office: [
        { name: 'Tom', age: 22, salutation: { title: 'Mr'}},    
        { name: 'Peter', age: 16, salutation: { title: 'Mr'}},  
        { name: 'John', age: 31, salutation: { title: 'Mr'}}
        
    ]
}


expected result = {
   place: {city: 'Bangalore', pin: 99999},
   office: [
   { name: 'Peter', age: 16, salutation: { title: 'Mr'}}
   ]
}
```

Note: comparison can be done by finding the properties of object and values but no comparison should be done hardcoding the properties
tried comparing the object but when we have an array of object i.e office, comparing with index(i.e 0,1) doesn't help as the array might not be sorted so couldn't proceed much

have tried the below code but it fails to get the desired output if the objects in an array are in different sequence as compared to the other array

```
ex. office1: [
        { name: 'Tom', age: 22, salutation: { title: 'Mr'}}, 
        { name: 'John', age: 31, salutation: { title: 'Mr'}}
    ]

office2: [
        { name: 'Tom', age: 22, salutation: { title: 'Mr'}},    
        { name: 'Peter', age: 16, salutation: { title: 'Mr'}},  
        { name: 'John', age: 31, salutation: { title: 'Mr'}}
        
    ]

  function findDiff(obj1, obj2) {
    var diffObj = Array.isArray(obj2) ? [] : {}
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj2).forEach(function(prop) {
        if(prop !=='lenght' ){
        if (typeof obj2[prop] === 'object') {
            diffObj[prop] = obj1[prop]== undefined? obj2[prop]: findDiff(obj1[prop], obj2[prop])
            if (Array.isArray(diffObj[prop]) && Object.getOwnPropertyNames(diffObj[prop]).length === 1 || Object.getOwnPropertyNames(diffObj[prop]).length === 0) {
                delete diffObj[prop]
            }
        }} else if(prop !=='lenght') {
        
        if(obj1[prop] !== obj2[prop]){
            diffObj[prop] = obj2[prop]
            }
        }
    });
    return diffObj
}
```

Comment: pleace add some code that you tried and don't successed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987909/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic deep diff between two objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572826/generic-deep-diff-between-two-objects)

Comment: here is what I have used

Answer (score 0):

This `compare` function seems to achieve exactly what you want :

```js
const baseObj =  {"grade":"A","queue":"1","myCollections":{"myCollection":[{"commonCollection":[{"winterCollection":[{"name":"ICE","isChilled":"true"}]}]}]},"remarks":{"remark":[{"name":"GOOD","category":"A","text":{"value":"Very Good"},"indicator":"good"}]}}

const updatedObj = {"grade":"A","queue":"1","myCollections":{"myCollection":[{"commonCollection":[{"winterCollection":[{"name":"ICE","isChilled":"true"},{"code":"SNOW","isChilled":"true"}]}]}]},"remarks":{"remark":[{"name":"GOOD","category":"A","text":{"value":"Very Good"},"indicator":"good"},{"name":"BEST","text":{"value":"Test"},"category":"O","indicator":"outstanding"}]}}

const compare = (a, b, allObj = true) => {
    if (typeof a !== 'object') return a === b ? null : b

    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        const arr = []

        b.forEach(e => {
            if (a.every(el => compare(el, e, true) !== null))
                arr.push(e)
        });

        return arr.length === 0 ? null : arr
    } else {
        const keys = Object.keys(b) // assuming a and b have the same properties
        const obj = allObj ? b : {}
        let changed = false
    
        keys.map(key => {
            const compared = compare(a[key], b[key], true)

            if (compared) {
                obj[key] = compared
                changed = true
            }
        })

        return changed ? obj : null
    }
}

const expectedResult = {"grade":"A","queue":"1","myCollections":{"myCollection":[{"commonCollection":[{"winterCollection":[{"code":"SNOW","isChilled":"true"}]}]}]},"remarks":{"remark":[{"name":"BEST","text":{"value":"Test"},"category":"O","indicator":"outstanding"}]}}

const result = compare(baseObj, updatedObj)
console.log(result)
console.log(expectedResult)

console.log(JSON.stringify(result) === JSON.stringify(expectedResult))
```

PS: I compared each pair but it is O(n^2). The best way is if you had an `id` property on every of array children.

Comment: please try with baseObj={"grade":"A","queue":"1","myCollections":{"myCollection":[{"commonCollection":[{"winterCollection":[{"name":"ICE","isChilled":"true"}]}]}]},"remarks":{"remark":[{"name":"GOOD","category":"A","text":{"value":"Very Good"},"indicator":"good"}]}}

Comment: updatedObj={"grade":"A","queue":"1","myCollections":{"myCollection":[{"commonCollection":[{"winterCollection":[{"name":"ICE","isChilled":"true"},{"code":"SNOW","isChilled":"true"}]}]}]},"remarks":{"remark":[{"name":"GOOD","category":"A","text":{"value":"Very Good"},"indicator":"good"},{"name":"BEST","text":{"value":"Test"},"category":"O","indicator":"outstanding"}]}}

Comment: thanks for your solution, sorry typo from my end expected result={"myCollections":{"myCollection":[{"commonCollection":[{"winterCollection":[{"code":"SNOW","isChilled":"true"}]}]}]},"remarks":{"remark":[{"name":"BEST","text":{"value":"Test"},"category":"O","indicator":"outstanding"}]}}

Comment: If you don’t want the unchanged properties to show on the root, you can specify it as the last arg : `compare(baseObj, updatedObj, false)`