# How can I compare a snapshot of Firebase RTDB and new data and only update the bits that are different?

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting data from an API and would like to push that data to Firebase RTDB. The problem I am facing is that the data from the API is live and parts of that data gets changed regularly.

For example, if the data comes from racing the lap number of the driver and the position changes. But, every other bit of data like venue and start time and start order remains the same.

At first push everything is great. But on second, the push destroys the data at the location and rewrites the new one. That down time may get reflected on the front end in angular. So, I am trying to avoid that.

How can I ensure that both the data in the database and the new one pulled from the live stream, only gets compared and any difference is automatically updated in Firebase RTDB ?

——————

Can Firebase do something like this

```
const target = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const source = { b: 4, c: 5 };

const returnedTarget = Object.assign(target, source);

console.log(target);
// Expected output: Object { a: 1, b: 4, c: 5 }
```

Comment: Nothing here interacts with Firebase in any way, so it's hard to say where that is going wrong. If you're asking how to determine the delta between two JavaScript objects, you'll probably want to search for how to do that without relating it to Firebase, TypeScript, or React. Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572826/generic-deep-diff-between-two-objects