# Actionscript - get difference between two objects

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Is there a built in function two compare two objects and give me a difference object? I'm also hoping to use that resulting object with differences and apply it to an object.  Are there built in ways to do that in actionscript or do I roll my own function like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1200865/37759

Answer (score 0):

There isn't build-in way to do this, only own function.

I suggest this code:

```
public static function diff(obj1:Object, obj2:Object):Object
{
    if(!obj1 || !obj2)
        return null;

    var diffObj:Object = {};
    for(var key:String in obj1)
    {
        if(key in obj2)
        {
            diffObj[key] = obj1[key] - obj2[key];
        }
    }

    return diffObj;
}

diff({prop1:1, prop2:2}, {prop2:2, prop1:3}) 
//output:
[object Object]:
    prop2:int = 0
    prop1:int = -2
```