# How to get difference of two JS objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

New to JavaScript and have very limited knowledge of JS objects. I want to get difference of two JS objects.

```
a=[{"month":1,"year":2015},{"month":2,"year":2015},{"month":3,"year":2015},{"month":4,"year":2015},{"month":5,"year":2015}];
b=[{"month":1,"year":2015},{"month":2,"year":2015},{"month":5,"year":2015}];
```

The result I dreamed should be

```
result=[{"month":3,"year":2015},{"month":4,"year":2015}];
```

I got the above format using `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference in JSON objects using Javascript/JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200562/difference-in-json-objects-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: what if `b` has something `a` doesn't have!! by difference did you also consider that scenario!

Comment: @demo  I tried several solutions available on SO. No one really worked for me or too complex for a simple problem. Otherwise I'm aware of the worth of time.

Comment: @AshadShanto possibly in this particular case it will not happen. I'm tracking this thing already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below should work for you,just use `filter` on array.

```
var a=[{"month":1,"year":2015},{"month":2,"year":2015},{"month":3,"year":2015},{"month":4,"year":2015},{"month":5,"year":2015}];
var b=[{"month":1,"year":2015},{"month":2,"year":2015},{"month":5,"year":2015}];

var diff = a.filter(function(a){
    return b.filter(function(b){
        return b.month == a.month && b.year == a.year
    }).length == 0
});

console.log(diff);
```

Comment: In my code I'm getting `undefined is not a function` How can I make it into a regular function form? so that I can declare it above the arrays where data is actually populating in them.

Comment: @LetMeCodeYou  unable to understand ,could you please elaborate more?  or show us your code?

Comment: Here we go, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LetMeCodeYou/1tyossmx/) It is just to show the structure of code where I'm using your function. Please suggest how I can overcome this `uncaught type error:undefined is not a function`

Comment: The problem is ,you are trying to use JSON on filter method,filter method only works with Object,I have updated your code at fiddle,just check and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69891/discussion-between-re350-and-letmecodeyou).

Comment: Actually I don't need the `JSON.stringify` at all. I removed it and error is gone. But the results are looks like this `differenceOfMonthYearData: 
 monthYearDataToBeMarked: ,
 monthYearDataToBeFiltered: ,,,` empty arrays. commas shows that there is some data. But it is not showing.